# How to create index mapping in Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch for .Net

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

I'm using the .NET nuget package 'Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch' (version 8) and trying to create an index mapping based on the below model.
How do I map the Employee members and its JobRole members? I tried using "Object" and "Nested", without luck.

Furthermore how do I exclude properties from being indexed? Attribute mapping like:

```
[Text(Name = "last_name")]
```

... is no longer supported in version 8. The only option is "fluent mapping".

Unfortunately there's only documentation available for version 7,
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/fluent-mapping.html

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public Employee EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
}


public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public JobRole[] JobRoles { get; set; }
}


public class JobRole
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

This is my code and as you can see I got lost halfway..

```
var createIndexResponse = client.Indices.Create<Company>("myindex", c => c
            .Mappings(m => m
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Keyword(s => s.CompanyName)
                 .Object<Employee> (x=>x.EmployeeInfo.EmployeeName  // Got lost here...
                )
            )
        );
```

Anyone?

Comment: Just wanted to +1 your question.  I'm in the same boat - did you make any progress?

Comment: @Drammy No I didn't. Very disappointing! I installed version 7.

Comment: I did some reading up and it appears that its not GA yet so it's best to use v7 whilst the full api is being developed

Comment: Attribute Mappings won't be implemented in v8, you have to use Fluent API.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/8.9/migration-guide.html#_attribute_mappings

Answer (score 3):

When creating new Properties, the IProperty it requests are the property types you'd assign to a field. Like TextProperty, ObjectProperty, NestedProperty, LongProperty:

```
    var response = await _client.Indices.CreateAsync<Company>("myindex", c => c
        .Mappings(map => map
            .Properties(p => p
            .Text(t => t.CompanyName)
            .Object(o => o.EmployeeInfo, objConfig => objConfig
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Text(t => t.EmployeeInfo.EmployeeName)
                    .Object(n => n.EmployeeInfo.JobRoles, objConfig => objConfig
                        .Properties(p => p
                            .Text(t => t.EmployeeInfo.JobRoles.First().RoleName)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ));
```

---

```
ObjectProperty jobRolesProperty = new ();
    jobRolesProperty.Properties.Add("roleName", new TextProperty());

    var response = await _client.Indices.CreateAsync<Company>("myindex", c => c
        .Mappings(map => map
            .Properties(
                new Properties<Company>()
                {
                    { "companyName", new TextProperty() },
                    { "employeeInfo", new ObjectProperty()
                    {
                            Properties = new Properties<Employee>()
                            {
                                { "employeeName", new TextProperty() },
                                { "jobRoles", jobRolesProperty }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        )
    );
```

---

```
 //Another syntax usage
ObjectProperty jobRolesProperty = new ();
    jobRolesProperty.Properties.Add("roleName", new TextProperty());

        var response = await _client.Indices.CreateAsync<Company>("myindex", c => c
        .Mappings(map => map
            .Properties(p => p
            .Text(t => t.CompanyName)
            .Object(o => o.EmployeeInfo, objConfig => objConfig
                .Properties(
                            new Properties<Employee>()
                            {
                                { "employeeName", new TextProperty() },
                                { "jobRoles", jobRolesProperty }
                            }
                )
            )
        )
    ));
```

---

The mapping created:

```
{
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "companyName": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "employeeInfo": {
            "properties": {
                "employeeName": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "jobRoles": {
                    "properties": {
                        "roleName": {
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    }
}
```

}

For managing settings you can check this answer:
[Elastic Search 8 Defining Analyzers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76757785/2069745)

Comment: Sounds great, but how is this an improvement compared to previous versions?

Comment: I can't comment as to the rationale in changing the library. This was the result of two weeks of implementation and banging my head against the wall until I smashed the correct buttons. Documentation would have been nice, but F12 on classes and reading the github repo ended up providing a solution.

Comment: Well, I think having fewer options to achieve the same thing in a library makes sense since this is more maintainable. 

But Elasticsearch should have provided such an answer as this one in their docs.